# How to Check and Compare Specific Child Value in Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below snapshot which returns `null` or any value like `62` or `32.50` etc.

```
for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
 String r_Fare = datas.child("tAmt").getValue(String.class);
```

I need to show `custom text` if value is `null`

[image]

I have tried  below but it is not working.

`dataSnapshot.child("tAmt").getValue().equals("null");`

How to check and compare firebase specific child value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the for loop you need to do the following:

```
String amt = datas.child("tAmt").getValue(String.class);
if(amt != null & !amt.isEmpty()){
  System.out.println(amt);
} 
else{}
```

Using the method `isEmpty()`, you can checks if this string is empty or not. It returns true, if length of string is 0 otherwise false. In other words, true is returned if string is empty otherwise it returns false

Comment: Thanks working like a charm. Can I check value as well like triptype="Single Trip" ?

Comment: if(triptype.equals("Single trip"))